# Is it possible to have php codes inside a javascript function?

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to have php codes inside a javascript function?I have a button which calls this function but it doesnt seem to work. The table doesnt show up and nothing happens

```
<script>
    function selectFunction()
    {
    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","study");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to mysql" . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sample_employers");

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['middlename'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td> <input type='button' value='Delete' </td>"; 
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: the php codes will execute first, then the output will be inside your javascript function. it will not call the php function using javascript.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is PHP is a server-side language whereas Javascript is a client-side language.

Comment: This is called as AJAX

Comment: The best way to do waht you want is to use ajax.the ajax function calls the php script which returns the table or even better a json file.if u want i write u an example.

Comment: @jmjassy27 It's an bad process to use PHP code like above in Your javascript function. If You elaborate Your requirement then I think You will get the proper answer

Comment: ok..id be greatful to see some example..thank you

Comment: @cocco id be grateful to have some example..

Comment: im really new to php, ajax and web dev stuff..can somebody show me an example??

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to do with it. If you want to do some JavaScript with reference to PHP e.g., like showing a number of images as specified by a userdata stored inside a database. This is usually done with the `script` tags in embedded in html.

However, if you want to do some PHP with JavaScript then the stuff that you're trying to do will not work whereas I'll recommend you to do the same with AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language and javascript is a client side language. So when you will call this page the result of the php page will come alanog with js code i.e php code will get first executed and not on javascript call.

There is one solution you can go for ajax call. Make a call to server side page and then execute your functionality.

here is a tutorial

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

You can call ajax via jQuery reference

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

Answer (score 0):

here you go...

i coded it fast... so maybe u need to check for more support anyway should work with most modern browsers.

**x** is the ajax function

**display** is the display function

when the page loads it searches for the first button and adds a click listener that executes the ajax function which calls async the display function.

save as 'example.php'

```
<?php
if($_GET['ajax']){
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","study");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){ echo "Failed to connect to mysql" . mysqli_connect_error(); }
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sample_employers");
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['middlename'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td> <input type='button' value='Delete' </td>"; 
  echo "</tr>";
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
}else{
?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script>
var x=function(a,b,c){c=new XMLHttpRequest;c.open('GET',a);c.onload=b;c.send()},
display=function(){
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('table')).innerHTML=this.response;
}
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick=function(){
  x('example.php?ajax=true',display)
 }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button>Load the table</button>
</body>
</html><?php
}
?>
```

a better approach would be to generate a json file with php containing the table object..
then u have more options to display the page in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap that php script in either a `document.getElementByID` or `document.write` method, choose which is most appropriate for your situation based on the context of your page. This is a rather odd way of going about this (AJAX is better), however this should work for you:

```
 <script>
 function selectFunction()
 {
      document.write('<?php
           error_reporting(0);
           $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","study");

           if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
                {
                     $html= "Failed to connect to mysql" . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
           $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sample_employers");
           while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                     $html= "<tr>";
                     $html.= "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
                     $html.= "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
                     $html.= "<td>" . $row['middlename'] . "</td>";
                     $html.= "<td> <input type='button' value='Delete' </td>"; 
                     $html.= "</tr>";

                }
           mysqli_close($con);
           $html = addslashes($html);
           echo $html;
      ?>');
 }
 </script>
 <!-- page contents here //-->
 <script>
      selectFunction();
 </script>
```